# How to create your own type based on function parameters?

Tags: typescript

Let's say there is a function to create an object.

```js
interface Params {
  name: string
}

const createTypedObject = (params: Params) => ({
  [params.name]: 1,
})
```

I create an object

```js
const obj = createTypedObject({ name: 'test' })
// Type obj {[p: string]: number}
```

How to make object type be `{test: number}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript isn't great at inferring generic types from created objects, so you're going to have to use a type assertion:

```
const createTypedObject = <P extends Params>(params: P) => ({
  [params.name]: 1,
}) as {[K in P['name']]: number}
```

Also note that the type of object literal `{name: 'test'}` is `{name: string}`, so to get the correctly narrowed property type, you'll have to add an `as const` to the parameter:

```
const obj = createTypedObject({name: 'test'} as const)
// obj: {test: number}
```

Alternatively, you can make `params` readonly, which will let TypeScript infer the narrowed type for literal objects, even without `as const`:

```
const createTypedObject = <P extends Params>(params: Readonly<P>) => ({
  [params.name]: 1,
}) as {[K in P['name']]: number}

const obj = createTypedObject({name: 'test'})
//    obj: {test: number}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgZ2QbwChlkRsIAuZHMKUAc0IF9DCiSEB7EG5BKCHEgAVAJ4AHCABMA8gCMAVhARhkAXmQAeVMggAPSCCl50mXAD4AFOIzYcVVAEp155JfYlkAbRtmcAOjIsCABdKgBGABpiZCZnODx8LwBpZFA0LwByIIhMkLDSAFcsOWgWGK4eVU5FcPU%20ASEIMUlZRWUwdxyqTMgaTLiYgHohz2QAPQB%20Vg5uXhqFACZ6-kERCWl5JRUu8h6%20sAHkBL45sEdh0c8p5lYPSt5VppbN9pV67V0DCCMTWwtrP97MgAEqCKTcAA2om05mcalc7hiJB8QMC5AKURicWOiRSaRAGWy5DyBRAxVKUHKsyqyAWK0a61aWw6u2C%20wg-UGJBGYxuTCAA)

Comment: YOu can get rid of `as const` assertion just by adding extra generic `Name`. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mx3OKN). Then you don't need to make it readonly

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine That's a valid alternative solution indeed, but I would choose the simplicity of the `Readonly` over introducing an additional generic parameter and intersection.